# Porque no se ejecutan comandos de Angular? (W10)

Tags: angular

El sistema responde al intentar ejecutar un comando de Angular

*script1.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.*

Intente habilitar scripts siguiendo instrucciones de varios tutoriales sin resultado

[image: error en VScode]

Comment: Utiliza la línea de comandos convencional, si estás con powershell tienes que habilitar unos pasos adicionales para ejecutar scripts no firmados. Si deseas usar powershell y firmar scripts, hay un link dentro del error, cosa de copiarlo y pegar en el navegador de tu preferencia y leer qué hay que hacer; gran parte de la programación y del mundo de la informática radica en esto. Es una recomendación en buen plan :)

Comment: Hola! no pude escribir mas info porque me habian cerrado el tema anterior. Ya leí todo eso y segui varios tutoriales de powershell pero sigue sin funcionarme

Answer (score 2):

Finalmente encontré la solución y la dejo por si a alguien más le sirve:

- Elemento de lista

Actualicé ([PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.2))

- Usé Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser unrestricted
- Reinicié la PC y ahora funciona correctamente!

Comment: A veces PowerShell no funciona, menos CMD. En lo personal utilizo la consola de [Git](https://git-scm.com/) interpreta comandos de Linux a la perfección.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto:

> Elimina `ng.ps1` del directorio `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\`despues intenta eliminar la cache de npm en `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\`

Tomado de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58044573/4326551).

Comment: Gracias por responder! pero tampoco me funciono :(